# Pagination implementation for a blog system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

Last night I was working on a project that I've embarked upon as a learning exercise. I decided to add a pagination feature to my blog system. I made an attempt at it and got close... but I decided to undo my changes and I searched online for other 'better' solutions. I found [this example](http://devproconnections.com/aspnet-mvc/aspnet-mvc-paging-done-perfectly) which uses PagedList.Mvc NuGet and [this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) from asp.net which uses the same package.

Long story short, I decided that before I install another package I would make one more attempt at my own implementation and I was successful... so, on to my question.

**Have I missed something important in my implementation that should make me want to reconsider my approach?**

Here's my relevant Action in my **HomeController.cs**:

```
public ActionResult Index(int num = 0)
{
    var postsPerPage = 3;
    ViewBag.startNum = num;

    using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        IEnumerable<Post> posts = uwork.PostRepository.GetAll().ToList();

        int totalPosts = posts.Count();
        ViewBag.pages = totalPosts / postsPerPage;
        int skip = num * postsPerPage;


        return View(posts.Skip(skip).Take(postsPerPage));
    }
}
```

and this is the relevant code from my **Index.cshtml**:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { num = 0 }, null)</li>
    @for (var i = 1; i < ViewBag.pages + 1; i++)
    {
        var cur = i.ToString();
        var name = i + 1;
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(name.ToString(), "Index", "Home", new { num = cur }, null)</li>

        if (i >= 10) { break; }

    }
</ul>
```

[image]

**Note:** I know there's going to be a bit more logic required in order to account for the remainder of pages after they are divided. But that's not my biggest concern as of yet.

Comment: This is a good question, and it looks like you did this fairly well, I too am relatively new to MVC. but I am not sure that I would do anything different.  I am excited to see the reviews of this code!

Comment: thanks for the kind words Lyle, I'm pretty new to asp.net myself. I asked this question because I just feel that if better programmers are choosing the other option... then they probably decided against the one I implemented. So, hopefully we'll get an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int num
```

What does `num` represent exactly? Number of pages? Number of posts per page? Current page number? Properly naming the variable would help a lot in clarity here.

---

```
var postsPerPage = 3;
```

Turn it into a parameter with default value 3. That way you can always decide later that the user can change this without much trouble.

---

Instead of using 0-based pages and then adding 1 to the presentation, I would consider using the reverse: 1-based pages and subtracting 1 when determining the pages to display. In essence this would turn your loop from `i = 2`, `name` becomes unnecessary and in your controller you use `int skip = (num - 1) * postsPerPage` instead.

---

```
using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
{
    IEnumerable<Post> posts = uwork.PostRepository.GetAll().ToList();

    int totalPosts = posts.Count();
    ViewBag.pages = totalPosts / postsPerPage;
    int skip = num * postsPerPage;


    return View(posts.Skip(skip).Take(postsPerPage));
}
```

`ViewBag.pages` (note the incorrect naming convention) indicates to me a collection of pages. In your case however, a more appropriate name would be `AmountOfPages`.

---

I feel like there's room for an optimization here: what if you have 100.000 pages? Or even just 100? You will load *all* your items *each time* someone visits the frontpage and you're only doing this to show the user how many pages of items there are. In fact you're not even doing that: you won't show them past 10 pages anyway!

I would argue that maybe you should just use two queries:

```
var totalPosts = uwork.PostRepository.GetAll().Count()
```

which will just perform a `select count(*) from posts` at the database side and another query that gives you your pages:

```
var pages = uwork.PostRepository.GetAll().Skip(skip).Take(postsPerPage)
```

Another way to keep performance in mind is to use

```
uwork.PostRepository.GetAll().Take(postsPerPage * 10).ToArray();
```

This will you give

1. The amount of posts (the exact amount being `pages.Length`)
2. The concrete posts (being `pages.Skip(skip).Take(postsPerPage)`)

The benefit of this is that it will only call the database once (network latency is one of your demons) with the downside being that it retrieves more items than you're interested in.

---

Instead of looping to `ViewBag.pages + 1` and possibly breaking out at `i >= 10`, I would just loop until `Math.Min(ViewBag.Pages + 1, 10)`.